# camera serial interface in c# on raspberrypi for windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, camera, mono, raspberry-pi3

i have been trying to create a program in c# that takes pictures on regular intervals of time through camera serial interface and saves it in a folder automatically. The problem is how do i enable camera from mono c# and start taking stills at regular intervals of time? Basically a Windows Form that has a button and a picture box that has live streaming of camera and button has a click event that captures a still image on camera. any help is very much appreciated..! thanks.

here i have code for my mono windows form in c#

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
public class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    Button btnLoad;
    Button btnSave;
    PictureBox pboxPhoto;
    Label lbl;
    TextBox tbx;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Text = "Hello AMD";            // Create and configure the Button

        btnLoad = new Button();
        btnLoad.Text = "&Load";
        btnLoad.Left = 10;
        btnLoad.Top = 10;
        btnLoad.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OnLoadClick);            // Create and configure the PictureBox

        btnSave = new Button();
        btnSave.Text = "&Save";
        btnSave.Left = 100;
        btnSave.Top = 10;
        btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OnSaveClick);            // Create and configure the PictureBox

        pboxPhoto = new PictureBox();
        pboxPhoto.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        pboxPhoto.Width = this.Width / 3;
        pboxPhoto.Height = this.Height / 3;
        pboxPhoto.Left = (this.Width - pboxPhoto.Width) / 2;
        pboxPhoto.Top = (this.Height - pboxPhoto.Height) / 2;
        pboxPhoto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;            // Add our new controls to the Form

        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "name";
        lbl.Left = 10;
        lbl.Top = 220;

        tbx = new TextBox();
        tbx.Left = 150;
        tbx.Top = 220;
                // Create and configure the PictureBox


        this.Controls.Add(btnLoad);
        this.Controls.Add(pboxPhoto);
        this.Controls.Add(btnSave);
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Controls.Add(tbx);

    }
    private void OnLoadClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Open Photo";
        dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pboxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
        }
        dlg.Dispose();

    }

    private void OnSaveClick(object sender , System.EventArgs e)

    {
        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash ";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c raspistill -o gg.jpg";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}
}
```

and what i thought would be is a form in which on OnLoadClick, the picture box has a real time video(not recording) from camera module and on OnSaveClick captures it at that particular time.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @admcfajn is this fine now?

Comment: Much better, thanks! The questions we ask are as much a contribution to this community as the answers. Nice work